# File is not saved into directory

Tags: java, spring, file

I want to use this code to to upload a file to Spring back end.

```
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "/opt";

    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO> uploadData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {

        if (file == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("You must select the a file for uploading");
        }

        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        String originalName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String name = file.getName();
        String contentType = file.getContentType();
        long size = file.getSize();

        LOG.info("inputStream: " + inputStream);
        LOG.info("originalName: " + originalName);
        LOG.info("name: " + name);
        LOG.info("contentType: " + contentType);
        LOG.info("size: " + size);

        try {

            // Get the file and save it somewhere
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO(originalName));
    }
```

For some reason the file is not saved into /opt directory. Can you give me some advice why the code is not working.

Into the log file I get:

```
2019-08-11 20:40:36,297 INFO  [stdout] (default task-17) 20:40:36.297 [default task-17] INFO  o.d.a.b.restapi.MerchantController - inputStream: java.io.BufferedInputStream@661c793f
2019-08-11 20:40:36,298 INFO  [stdout] (default task-17) 20:40:36.298 [default task-17] INFO  o.d.a.b.restapi.MerchantController - originalName: Screenshot 2019-07-14 at 14.33.41.png
2019-08-11 20:40:36,299 INFO  [stdout] (default task-17) 20:40:36.298 [default task-17] INFO  o.d.a.b.restapi.MerchantController - name: file
2019-08-11 20:40:36,299 INFO  [stdout] (default task-17) 20:40:36.299 [default task-17] INFO  o.d.a.b.restapi.MerchantController - contentType: image/png
2019-08-11 20:40:36,300 INFO  [stdout] (default task-17) 20:40:36.300 [default task-17] INFO  o.d.a.b.restapi.MerchantController - size: 20936
```

Comment: What do you mean *not working*? What it does? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: file is not created. I tried your deleted post - it's working

Comment: I undeleted it. I deleted it because i was not sure that the problem is that the file is not created. In your post you mention *For some reason the file saved into /opt directory.* which really confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Paths#get` try to do the following:

```
File newFile = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER, file.getOriginalFileName());
LOG.info("New file location: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath()); //Log the path
Files.write(newFile.toPath(), bytes);
```

Instead of using `+` operator to a bunch of `String`s in order to create the paths of a new file, it is always better to use a `java.io.File` constructor. Then use `toPath` method in order to get it.